# Get/Set methods wrong output

Tags: java

Working on a small application that allows DVD's and lead actors objects to display from two different classes but I'm getting the following output.

```
person.Person@10ed7f5c
```

Could anyone offer any insight into what I'm going wrong?

DVD Class

```
public class DVD {

private String title;
private Person leadActor;
private int noOfStars;


public DVD (String a,Person person, int b) {

title = a;
leadActor = person;
noOfStars = b;   

}    

public String getTitle(){

return title;

}

public void setTitle(String title){

this.title = title;    
}

public Person getLeadActor(){

return leadActor;
}

public void setLeadActor(Person leadActor){

this.leadActor = leadActor;
}

public int getNoOfStars(){

return noOfStars;
}

public void setNoOfStarts(int noOfStars){

this.noOfStars = noOfStars;

}

@Override
public String toString() {

String s = "Title " + title + "/r" + "Actor:" + leadActor + "/r" + noOfStars;

return s;
}

}
```

Person class

```
public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;    


public Person (String a, String b){

firstName = a;
lastName = b;


}

public String getfirstName(){


    return firstName;
}

public void setfirstName(String firstName){


   this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getlastName(){


    return lastName;
}

public void setlastName(String lastName){

this.lastName = lastName;
}
}
```

And my class to create objects and call the toString

```
public class DvdTest {


private DVD d1;

public static void main (String [] args){

Person p2 = new Person ("Leonardo", "Decaprio");

DVD d1 = new DVD ("Inception",p2,4); 

System.out.println (p2.toString());

}
}
```

Comment: Override the `toString` method in your `Person` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the `DVD` class, you need to override the `toString()` method in your `Person` class as well. Currently it is printing value returned from the default implementation of [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which is something like this

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Here is a sample IDE generated implementation you'd use.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to print `leadActor` which is of type `Person`, then `Person` class `toString` method is called. Default `toStirng` method prints the classname and hash separated by `@` character. Thats why in your output you see this:

```
Person@10ed7f5c
```

In order to print Person objects in a beautiful way, you need to override `toString` method in your `Person` class also. Here is toString implementaton generated using eclipse:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pricing [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
            + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thats not the wrong output.

the default toSTring of Object returns this. Class+hashcode

If you want a custom message override toString of Person

```
public String toString() {
    return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
}
```

Note: you already did this in your DVD class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to over-ride the `toString()` method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Person [firstName=%s, lastName=%s]", firstName, lastName);
}
```